# Combining UPDATE, JOIN and ORDER BY in one MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following code at the moment:

```
mysql_query("SET @standing = 0") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET @league = 0") or die(mysql_error());

$query="UPDATE member_leagues
    SET 
        standing = (@standing := IF(@league = league_id,@standing+1,0)) + 1,
        league_id = @league := league_id
    WHERE active='1'
    ORDER BY league_id,pts_total DESC";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

What this does (correctly) is the following:

It updates the `standing` column in the `member_leagues` table in such a way that it groups rows by the `league_id` column and ranks each group by the `pts_total` column. For example, take the following table before and after the query.

Before:

```
id | league_id | pts_total | standing | member_id
1  | 14        | 25        | 0        | 234
2  | 8         | 19        | 0        | 89
3  | 14        | 12        | 0        | 35
4  | 14        | 10        | 0        | 200
5  | 8         | 16        | 0        | 94
```

After:

```
id | league_id | pts_total | standing | member_id
1  | 14        | 25        | 1        | 234
2  | 8         | 19        | 1        | 89
3  | 14        | 12        | 2        | 35
4  | 14        | 10        | 3        | 200
5  | 8         | 16        | 2        | 94
```

So, you see, it ranks members within each league (as distinguished by the league_id). Now, the problem: the database structure has changed and the pts_total column no longer exists in this table. It's been moved to a different table named `teams`, which can be joined to this table by `member_leagues.member_id=teams.manager_id`. How do I alter the query above to do the same thing it does now, but rank the members based on the `pts_total` column in the `teams` table?

I've tried the following, but got the error `Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY`:

```
mysql_query("SET @standing = 0") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET @league = 0") or die(mysql_error());

$query="UPDATE member_leagues left join teams on member_leagues.member_id=teams.manager_id
    SET 
        member_leagues.standing = (@standing := IF(@league = member_leagues.league_id,@standing+1,0)) + 1,
        member_leagues.league_id = @league := member_leagues.league_id
    WHERE member_leagues.active='1'
    ORDER BY member_leagues.league_id,teams.pts_total DESC";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

This is getting too complicated for me, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html):

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named
>   in table_references that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER
>   BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that. But can you suggest a solution? Since it apparently can't be done with 1 query, is there a better solution than iterating through both tables separately to get the values?